# Identical inheritance pattern in multiple classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, trailblazer

I have the following situation:

```
class A < CommonParent
  ... some code ...

  class IdenticalDescendent < self
    identical_statement_0
    identical_statement_1
  end
end

class B < CommonParent
  ... some other code ...

  class IdenticalDescendent < self
    identical_statement_0
    identical_statement_1
  end
end
```

I have this situation a lot. Like, there are about forty `IdenticalDescendent` classes in my app. I like the pattern, it allows me to call `A::IdenticalDescendent` or `B::IdenticalDescendent` or whatever to access certain related behaviours in different domains (specified by `A` or `B`). For reasons, I can't just completely abstract the problem away by re-designing the behaviour clustering.

So the general form of my question is how do I automate the generation of IdenticalDescendent in all of these. There ARE descendants of `CommonParent` that don't invoke this pattern, so the action probably shouldn't happen there. I imagine it should happen in a mixin or something, but I find that if I just try to do:

```
class A < CommonParent
  include CommonBehaviour

  ... some code ...
end

module CommonBehaviour
  ... what ...
end
```

I can't figure out how to write `CommonBehaviour` to allow for the IdenticalDescendent to descend from the including class.

Help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: Give a real life example, please. It’s hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. The only guess so far is: you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I got it covered, thanks folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can automate your pattern by using the callback (hook) [Class#inherited](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited):

```
class CommonParent
  def self.inherited(klass)
    return unless klass.superclass == CommonParent
    klass.const_set(:Descendent, Class.new(klass) do
      def x
        puts "in x"
      end
    end)
  end
end

class A < CommonParent
  def a
    puts "in a"
  end   
end

d = A::Descendent.new #=> #<A::Descendent:0x007f99620172e8> 
d.a                   #   in a
d.x                   #   in x

class B < CommonParent
  def b
    puts "in b"
  end
end

d = B::Descendent.new #=> #<B::Descendent:0x007f99618b18f0> 
d.b                   #   in b
d.x                   #   in x
d.a                   #=> NoMethodError:... (as expected)
```

Note that, without:

```
return unless klass.superclass == CommonParent
```

the creation of `A::Descendent` would trigger `inherited` with `klass => Descendent`, causing an anonymous subclass of `Descendent` to be created, etc., resulting in a "stack level too deep exception."

Answer (score 1):

The answer I was looking for is to use block notation for `Class.new` inside a `self.included` callback. I have this now:

```
module CommonDescendant
  def self.included(base)
    descendant_class = Class.new(base) do
      ... put my desired common behavior here ...
    end

    base.const_set :Descendant, descendant_class
  end
end

class A
  include CommonDescendant

  ... unique behavior ...
end

class B
  include CommonDescendant

  ... unique other behavior ...
end
```

And this gives us the design I want!

Comment: Looks good. You can put `include CommonDescendent` in the `included` method. (See my answer.) I noticed you decided to change the spelling of "descendent". Sorry, but "descendant" only applies to plants and animals (including humans). Wait: what happened to `CommonParent`?

Comment: I don't follow your code here, in part because there is no reference to `CommonParent`.  In any event, `included` will be triggered each time you create a subclass of `CommonParent` or a subclass of that subclass, etc., resulting in "stack level too deep". (See my answer for how to avoid that.) Secondly, `include CommonDescendant` doesn't do anything, because that module contains no instance methods.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest separating descendant class and method generation. Of course, you could toss everything into a `class_eval` block (which will positively reek).

Something like the following (completely untested)

```
module CommonDescendants
  Descendant = Class.new(self) do 
    include CommonDescendantMethods
  end
end

module CommonDescendantMethods
end

class A < CommonParent
  extend CommonDescendants
end
```

Comment: The behavior that you're going for around `Descendant = Class.new(self)` is what I'm missing, though. That code doesn't work, because in the context `self` is the module `CommonDescendants`, not the including class. That having been said, I forgot that the `Class.new` syntax accepted a block, so I may play around with that to see if I can work it from there.

Comment: Parsing the module CommonDescendants raises the exception, `"TypeError: superclass must be a Class (Module given)"`. That's because `self` is `CommonDescendents` (I've corrected spelling), which is not a class. `extend CommonDescendents` makes no sense because `CommonDescendents` contains no methods and class methods are not desired anyway. I've downvoted your answer, which I rarely do, not just because it's wrong, but because you presented it without testing.